# Add a column that contains a list of ID's from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

**Problem**
I'd like to perform a `groupby` on a dataframe, with the resulting dataframe containing a column with its elements being a list of the `groupby` parameter.

**Example**
I have a dataframe `ship_cluster` with `ShipID`, `latitude`, `longitude` and a column named `cluster`.

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({"ShipID": [7, 7, 8, 9],
                           "latitude": [51.872842, 51.872874, 51.872794, 51.872946],
                           "longitude": [5.810379, 5.810729, 5.810754, 5.810548],
                           "cluster": [0, 1, 0, 0]})
print(df)

"ShipID" latitude  longitude cluster
7        51.872842 5.810379  0
7        51.872874 5.810729  1
8        51.872794 5.810754  0
9        51.872946 5.810548  0
```

The desired output I wish to have would be:

```
         latitude  longitude ShipID
cluster                            
0        51.872860 5.810560  [7, 8, 9]
1        51.872874 5.810729  [7]
```

So per `cluster`, I'd like to see the `ShipID` in a list. Obviously, I can first do a groupby:

```
ship_cluster[["latitude", "longitude", cluster"]].groupby("cluster").mean()
```

but I do not know the next step, nor a simplified method. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need if need aggregate by `cluster`:

```
d = {"latitude":'mean', "longitude":'mean', "ShipID":lambda x: x.tolist()}
df = ship_cluster.groupby("cluster").agg(d)
print (df)
         latitude  longitude ShipID
cluster                            
0        51.87270    5.81362    [7]
1        51.85040    5.86688    [7]
2        51.87410    5.91493    [7]
3        51.85500    5.96898    [7]
4        51.88101    6.00426    [7]
5        51.87368    6.03096    [7]
```

Or by `ShipID`:

```
d = {"latitude":'mean', "longitude":'mean', "cluster":lambda x: x.tolist()}
df = ship_cluster.groupby("ShipID").agg(d)
print (df)
         latitude  longitude             cluster
ShipID                                          
7       51.867815   5.933272  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```